# Как ускорить время чтения файла в Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas

Как можно ускорить чтение файлов в Google Colab?

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

listdata1 = {}
listdata1 = os.listdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/folder/")

for i1 in range(len(listdata1)):
    df1[i1] = pd.read_json("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/folder/"+listdata1[i1])
print("Well done! iter:", i1)
```

Comment: Не хватает данных о производительности, сколько сейчас занимает по времени, какой участок кода вызывает задержки (предполагаю, что с `pd.read_json` но мало ли)?

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном куске кода практически все время тратится на чтение файлов (`disk IO`) и парсинг JSON файлов. Единственное, что приходит на ум в данном случае это прочитать один раз все файлы и сохранить словарь `df1` в бинарном формате. Например как Pickle файл.

Pickle файлы читаются очень быстро и больше не надо будет парсить JSON структуры.

Comment: Можете пример показать о чем вы имеете ввиду? Вы кажется только решили мое основную проблему.